# Iterate over all files in directory from a specified relative path

Tags: java, relative-path

I want to use this kind of "relative" path, because I want to be able to include all the files in this directory as part of a github project that others can download and just run.

So I want to just jump up once in the structure `../` and then go down into one of the directories there, `word_lists_1` and read out all the files.

6<sup>th</sup>

This code keeps crashing though. Why is that?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<File>();

    final String directoryName = "../word_lists_1";
    listf( directoryName, arrayList );

    for(File elem : arrayList)
    {
        System.out.println(elem+"  ");
    }

}

public static void listf(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files)
{
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList)
    {
        if (file.isFile())
        {
            files.add(file);
        }
        else if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.listf(Main.java:49)
at Main.main(Main.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

so it doesn't like line `49` which is this:

```
for (File file : fList)
```

Comment: check if `getParent` method works for you.. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29

Comment: just apply that to the directory name?

Comment: apply it to your `File` object of that directory name.

Comment: I don't think it works, at least not how I tried it.

Comment: Surely you can be more specific than "keeps crashing"? Is there an exception thrown? If so, what is its stacktrace?

Comment: my bad. hang on a sec.

Comment: So the exception is thrown at line 49 of Main.java. Which line is that in your quoted code?

Comment: `for (File file : fList)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need the file *canonical path* to resolve the parent accordingly and avoid any path to be unresolved which may need to a some being `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

One simple implementation to resolve the a directory out of a realtive path to the current directory then display of load its tree hierarchy would be as follows:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws URISyntaxException, IOException
    {

        File currentDir = new File( "." ); // Read current file location
        File targetDir = null;
        if (currentDir.isDirectory()) {
            File parentDir = currentDir.getCanonicalFile().getParentFile(); // Resolve parent location out fo the real path
            targetDir = new File( parentDir, "word_lists_1" ); // Construct the target directory file with the right parent directory
        }
        if ( targetDir != null && targetDir.exists() )
        {
            listDirectoryAndFiles( targetDir.toPath() );
        }
    }

    private static void listDirectoryAndFiles( Path path ) throws IOException
    {
        DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream( path );
        for ( Path p : dirStream )
        {
            System.out.println( p.getFileName() );
            if ( p.toFile().isDirectory() )
            {
                listDirectoryAndFiles( p );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You may just need to adjust the `listDirectoryAndFiles(java.nio.file.Path)` method to meet your needs.

*Note that the aforementioned implementation uses the new I/O capabilities out of Java 7.*

Comment: I get the error `Error:(93, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method listDirectoryFiles(java.nio.file.Path)
  location: class Main`

Comment: Sorry, there first method call was holding a wrong method name... I've fixed it and you may try again with the current sample.

Comment: that wasn't it. it worked when i removed the line `File parentDir = currentDir.getCanonicalFile().getParentFile(); // Resolve parent location out fo the real path`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand from your requirements

- you are in current execution directory and you then want to traverse
  back one directory and get into some other folder by the name
  "word_lists_1"

if I understand your question correctly ,I would have implemented it like

```
String str=System.getProperty("user.dir");
String filePath = str+"/../word_lists_1";
```

if you are in some other directory then you can do

```
String str=Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
String filePath = str+"/../word_lists_1";
```

hope this helps!

good luck!

Comment: I just tried both of those, but they didn't work. i'm using intellij. I'm in a directory called `src` above that is the project directoy, and that's where is located `word_lists_1`. i want it to be fully dynamic tho, so someone random can download it off github and just run it, you know what I mean?

Comment: this is the error message i got:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main.listf(Main.java:52)
 at Main.main(Main.java:30)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.

Comment: Yaaa I got u entirely now, will have to think on similar lines